TV series with a smart female character whose brother or ex-boyfriend shows up who is smarter and is in some military/spy organization?
I am pretty sure this is a sci-fi series, but there's a chance it isn't. For some reason, I was thinking it was Stargate SG-1, but I can't confirm it. I don't remember a whole lot, but here are some points I think capture the essence:

The guy is well built - think Channing Tatum.

The lady is smart, maybe a bit OCD, a trait which he shares.

They're together for maybe two episodes, then she has him arrested, or maybe she just reports him to the higher-ups.

He portrays himself as some super-spy/special services guy when he shows up, but there's something off - he's not a super good guy - he lacks moral judgement, but he's definitely way skilled and part of an organization - either spy or paramilitary.

I seem to recall they are pairing up to do an investigation of a military organization where paperwork and a coverup, maybe murder, is involved, forgeries, etc.

The lady isn't the only main character of the show, but she's a regular and the guy totally shows her up to her peeps.


As I think of more points, or as y'all weigh in, I'll try to add more stuff. As for Sci-fi components, it's set on Earth, but that is probably just a one-off for these episodes. I don't remember anything particularly sci-fi-ish, but maybe alien technology (nothing I can specify) or alien's in disguise, but again I can't remember that being specific to these episodes. It's a little vague, hopefully, this is enough to kick things off.

SG Atlantis indeed has Rodney Mackay and his prodigy sister Jeannie, but the rest of the plot points are off.

@user108131 My first immediate thought also, but genders are reversed and as you said the other plot points don't match.

Maybe from "Eureka" (2006) TV show? Or Warehouse 13?
